# How to integrate quastion the answer is arc tan but i can recognize the angel

Tags: integration

How can i solve this?I know it's going to be arctan but i can't
figure out it
s angle...
And i can't solve this

```
> x÷(x^2+y^2) dy
$$\int\frac{1}{\ x÷( x^2+y^2)}\,\text{d}y.$$

 **I forgot how i should write it's angle and dy integrate**
```

Comment: Read again the general directions to properly write questions **and mathematics** in this site. As it is your question makes no sense at all.

Comment: I'm with mobile phone i can not correct this

Comment: Are you asking what $$ \int\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy$$ will be?

Comment: Yes Exactly @naji

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Write your integral in the form
$$\frac{1}{x}\int\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2}dy$$ and Substitute $$t=\frac{y}{x}$$
The result is given by $$\arctan \left( {\frac {y}{x}} \right) +C$$

Comment: No, it cancels with the $x$ in the numerator in the integrand

Comment: Can you explain me more?

Comment: It is $$\frac{x}{x^2\left(1+\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\right)^2}$$